# What aren't we using a double array?

Tags: c++, c, printf, scanf

I came across this code

Input:

```
3
0.1227...
0.517611738...
0.7341231223444344389923899277...
```

```
int N; 
char x[110]; 
int main() {
scanf("%d\n", &N);
while (N--) { 
scanf("0.%[0-9]...\n", &x); 
printf("the digits are 0.%s\n", x);
```

And I cannot understand few things:

1.Why aren't we using a double 
  array(since the input value is 
  double)?

2.What purpose do those three dots 
  ... in scanf after [0-9] are 
  serving? and

3.Why are we not using any format 
  specifier (d in this case) after 
  [0-9] in scanf?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the documentation for `scanf`. A `double` only has so much precision, this code is reading in an arbitrary (well, only up to 110 of them, or you'll encounter issues) number of digits after `"0."`.

Comment: As for `double`, the program is reading text. Don't overthink it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why aren't we using a double array(since the input value is double)?

The inputs could be captured as `double` as well as characters. `double` does have a limit of significant digits. For whatever reason, your code is storing the input as characters.

> What purpose do those three dots ... in scanf after [0-9] are serving?

The three dots aren't serving any purpose except if they are part of the input then up to three dots are removed before the next `scanf`. An input of `0,123` will be successfully scanned as will `0.123...`. If the input was `0.123abc` the `abc` will be left in the input stream and cause problems in the current code.

> Why are we not using any format specifier (d in this case) after [0-9] in scanf?

`%[]` is a format specifier. Sometimes called a scanset. It stores characters. It can be inclusive or exclusive.
`%[0-9]` is inclusive. It will accept digits. It will stop on the first character that is not a digit.
A `d` following the specifier would behave the same as the dots. With `0.%109%[0-9]d`, an input of `0.123down` would scan `0.123d` leaving `own` in the input stream to cause problems later on in the current code.
It is a good practice to provide the array limit to prevent writing too many characters to the array. for [110] use `%109[0-9]`. That allows one character for the terminating zero.

EDIT: code example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int N;
char x[110];

int main ( void) {
    scanf("%d\n", &N);
    while (N--) {
        scanf(" 0.%109[0-9]...", x);
        printf("the digits are 0.%s\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this exact code on codeblocks but it is not producing desired output and is going awry. Could you tell why?

Comment: 3                                        
0.123...                                 
0.1234...                                
the digits are 0.123                     
0.12345...                               
the digits are 0.1234

Comment: First of all it is not accepting 3 inputs in a single run, only 2 inputs.  It is printing the first string right after accepting second string and second string after accepting third one. If you run it yourself you will get a clear idea.

Comment: user3121023 yes it worked. But what good adding a space and removing a \n did?